# Data bind to a controller function return

Tags: sapui5

is there a way to bind a view property to a return of a controller function?

Something like this:

```js
sap.ui.define([ "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", 
                "sap/ui/model/Filter", 
                "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
                "pelissari/soficom/launchpad/model/formatter",
                "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"], 
                function(Controller, Filter, FilterOperator, formatter,JSONModel) {
 return Controller.extend("pelissari.soficom.launchpad.controller.TileGroup", {
  isEditable:function(){
   var ol_ListaTiles = this.getView().byId("tileList");
   return ol_ListaTiles.getEditable(true);
  }
 })
});
```

```html
<OverflowToolbarButton text="teste" icon="sap-icon://delete" valueLiveUpdate="true" visible="isEditable"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate json object and change the visibility in a function depending on your need;

```
var testJSON = {test:false};
this.testModel = new JSONModel();
this.testModel.setData(testJSON);
this.getView().byId('testLabel').setModel(this.testModel);
```

Binding;

```
<Label id="testLabel" text="test" visible="{/test}"></Label>
```

If you want to change the value;

> this.testModel.setProperty("/test",true);